# Не работает JavaScript в WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Вот HTML

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="other/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="other/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="other/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="other/pagepiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.js"></script>
<script src="other/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Все закомментил и подключил в functions.php

```
function acquirev_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main_style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'site_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/animate.css' );
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_lib', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array(''), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array(''), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pagepiling_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/pagepiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.js', array(''), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wow_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/wow.min.js', array(''), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array(''), '1.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'acquirev_scripts' );
```

Не работает javascript. При загрузке страницы нечего не происходит. Что тут не так?

Выдает такую ошибку

```
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'report-sample'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'unsafe-inline'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «https:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «http:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'report-sample'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'unsafe-inline'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «https:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «http:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'report-sample'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'unsafe-inline'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «https:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «http:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'report-sample'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'unsafe-inline'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «https:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «http:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'report-sample'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «'unsafe-inline'» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «https:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Content Security Policy: Игнорирую «http:» внутри script-src: указано «strict-dynamic»
Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://acquirev01.myjino.ru/wp-content/themes/acquirev/js/scripts.js?ver=5.4» не удалась.
```

Comment: Пути неправильные, скорее всего. Ошибки в консоли.

Comment: И зависимость от jquery не указана

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'acquirev_scripts' );
function acquirev_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'site', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pagepiling_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/pagepiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/animate.css' );
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pagepiling', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/pagepiling/jquery.pagepiling.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/other/wow.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mainscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
```